# Math error using data from sqlite3 in python program?

Tags: python, sqlite, sum

```
from math import *
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('person.sqlite3')

def main():
    agelist = conn.execute("SELECT age from person where age!='NA'")
    ages = []
    for row in agelist: ages += [row [0]]

    sumthis = []
    for row in agelist:
        sumthis += [row[0**2]]
    sqrted=sum(sumthis)
    print(sqrted)
```

I am trying to square every row of data in agelist, and find the sum of all of those squared numbers. Right now this is giving me 0 as an answer. I want sum(age^2 for each age in ages list)
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should replace

```
sumthis += [row[0**2]]
```

With,

```
sumthis += [row[0]**2]
```

Or, more appropriately,

```
sumthis.append(row[0]**2)
```

That's because,  forming a new list and add two list at every iteration isn't a good idea.

For the same reason, change

```
for row in agelist: ages += [row [0]]
```

To:

```
for row in agelist: ages.append(row [0])
```

Comment: I have adjusted my code to use append, however it is still giving me 0 as the answer. I am not sure it is using the numbers from agelist, am I pulling the rows from agelist properly?

Comment: Try `for row in agelist: print row [0]` to check actually what value you are getting.